# How can I create a Popup when i press a button in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, popupwindow

When I press a button and N>100 appears in the screen a popup that says "Wrong Number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this tutorial: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)